# Meson / Ninja build system - How to run custom script at Uninstall?

Tags: ninja, meson-build

Meson/Ninja provide an easy method to run a script at install time.
For example, this line will tell Meson to run the `glib-compile-schemas` command to compile the GSettings on Linux (system configuration options).

`meson.add_install_script('glib-compile-schemas', schemas_dir)`
(this command will be automatically run when the user executes `ninja install`)

How can I tell Meson to run a custom command at **uninstall**?
In this specific case I would like to delete (or at least reset to default) the key-value pairs in GSettings. To reset them, I have found that the command is `gsettings reset-recursively <path>` (successfully tested in terminal).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding custom uninstall script is [still being discussed](https://github.com/mesonbuild/meson/issues/1974), it's proposed quite some time ago but not yet implemented. It looks this task is typically left for package manager (and therefore to corresponding packaged scripts).

But I agree, there is some illogical asymmetry in case of meson **install** command. As a workaround, you can create your own target:

```
 run_target('my-uninstall', command : ['scripts/uninstall.sh'])
```

The drawbacks, of course, are that it should be invoked explicitly, cannot override, append or rename internal ***uninstall*** target and script should have executable permissions.

The internal, reserved [***uninstall*** target](https://mesonbuild.com/Release-notes-for-0-38-0.html#uninstall-target), however, does revert all explicit install operations:

> Meson allows you to uninstall an install step by invoking the
> uninstall target. This will remove all files installed as part of
> install. Note that this does not restore the original files. **This also
> does not undo changes done by custom install scripts (because they can
> do arbitrary install operations).**

Comment: Thank you very much for your accurate reply and for finding the time to share your knowledge!! I think at this point I will create a custom `uninstall.py` script that will execute `ninja uninstall` plus the other custom commands

Comment: I don't think it's possible, meson and thus ninja already have uninstall target that reverts  all install operations but, obviously, not reverting any operations done from within add_install_script(), check this https://mesonbuild.com/Release-notes-for-0-38-0.html (top)

Comment: Solution (waiting for official Meson feature): I created a bash script called `uninstall.sh`, which calls `sudo ninja uninstall` and also takes care of other custom operations that need to be performed. I tested it and it works. Thank you for helping me to better understand the problem.

Comment: ok, I see, it's the other way round, I am glad that it helped!